# How can i mass update a checkbox on campaign members from a related list?

Tags: field-update, update, campaign-member

i have added a lookup to a custom object on campaign member that shows them on the related list for my custom object. i need to be able to show a checkbox for a custom fields on campaign member, 'attended', and be able to check multiple records, then hit update and have it update all the checkboxes.

anyone figured out how to do this?

i've seen the mass edit update app but i don't see it working with campaign members....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the smart-tables app, just add the lighting component to the layout choose the object and fields and use the mass update button:

Adding a related list: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ly2C_aI7PA
Bulk update in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6oMU0Pypxo

By the way, you can also use the explorer tab for quick edits or create a dedicated tab for the child-records.

More guides (on ZaapIT's website): https://www.zaapit.com/page/Videos